# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'val')

Tags: javascript, radiobutton

Tengo mis RadioButton:

```
<div class="col-md-2 ml-auto">
    <div class="form-check">
        <br>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id-tipo="RadioDiario" checked >
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
            Diario
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 ml-auto">
    <div class="form-check">
        <br>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id-tipo="RadioSemanal">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
            Semanal
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y al dar clic en un boton para guardar la nueva información, entra a una function de js donde, creo una variable allRadio, y hago una function donde recolecto los radio que este seleccionados e ingreso a la variable ya declarada al inicio, mi intencion es tomar ese dato y ponerlo dentro de un arreglo, ya que este lo envio despues como json de ajax, entonces lo que requiero es que en la variable me mande como id-tipo pues ya sea RadioDiario o Semanal, como puedo hacerlo?

me sale este error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'val')

```
var allRadio;
$('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function () {
    allRadio = ($(this).attr('id-tipo')).val();
});

var unidad = {
    _id: id,       
    _radio: allRadio

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para coger el valor del atributo `id-tipo` tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
var allRadio;
$('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function () {
    allRadio = $(this).attr('id-tipo');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

si no lo he entendido mal quieres poder marcar ambos radios, si es en ese caso te recomiendo usar `<input type="checkbox">` en caso de que lo que quieres sea solo poder seleccionar uno de los dos radios entonces tu codigo esta mal formulado, ambos `radios` deben de tener el mismo `name` para que cuando marques uno se desmarque el otro y un `value` si quieres recojer el valor que tenga el seleccionado, te dejo aquí un pequeño ejemplo.

```js
function loadEvents() {
  const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  btn.addEventListener("click", showChecked);
}

function showChecked() {
  const radioChecked = document.querySelector('input[name="frequency"]:checked').value;
  alert(`Has marcado ${radioChecked}`);
}

// Esta linea es solo para cargar los eventos una vez haya cargado el DOM de la pagina
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadEvents);
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="daily" type="radio" name="frequency" value="diario" checked>
  <label for="daily"> Diario </label>
</div>


<div>
  <input id="weekly" type="radio" name="frequency" value="semanal">
  <label for="weekly">Semanal</label>
</div>

<button id="btn">Pillar marcado</button>
```

En caso de lo que quieres es poder marcar los dos te dejo aquí un ejemplo de como seria de una forma sencilla con `<input type="checkbox">`.
En el ejemplo puedes ver como a ambos se le puede poner como `name` `frequency[]` esto es para cuando se envían los datos a un servidor `php` estos llegan en forma de array. Tambien puedes ver que a diferencia del primer ejemplo aquí se usa `document.querySelectorAll` el cual devuelve un array por lo cual recojas todos los elementos que cumplan con el parámetro pasado.

```js
function loadEvents() {
    const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", showChecked);
}

function showChecked() {
    const radioChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="frequency[]"]:checked');
    let checked = Array.from(radioChecked).map(e => e.value);
    alert(`Has marcado ${checked}`);
}

// Esta linea es solo para cargar los eventos una vez haya cargado el DOM de la pagina
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadEvents);
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="daily" type="checkbox" name="frequency[]" value="diario" checked>
  <label for="daily"> Diario </label>
</div>


<div>
  <input id="weekly" type="checkbox" name="frequency[]" value="semanal">
  <label for="weekly">Semanal</label>
</div>

<button id="btn">Pillar marcado</button>
```